# QR decomposition with different metric

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to find a QR decomposition of a matrix $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{QR}$ but with the condition that $\mathbf{Q}^{\dagger}\mathbf{S}\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{I}$, where $\mathbf{S}$ is some general metric. For example, $\mathbf{S}$ might be
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{S} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
or something like that. Obviously we can use standard routines (Gram-Schmidt, for example) to do the case when $\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{I}$, but how might I accomplish this generalized case? I'd rather not re-write a QR routine if possible, but rather make use of existing LAPACK routines.

Comment: If $S$ is positive definite then you can adapt the same algorithms, replacing Euclidean inner products with $S$-inner products. But otherwise I'm not sure this is even guaranteed to be possible, and if it is I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: How can you have $\mathbf{Q}^{\dagger}\mathbf{S}\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{I}$ when $\mathbf{S} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$? If $Q$ is orthogonal the former implies that $S$ is similar to $I$...

Comment: @Hyperplane The point is that $Q^\dagger S Q = I$ is replacing the usual orthogonality requirement for QR.

Comment: @ian I guess the problem is that $S$ would need to have the same inertia as the identity matrix which is impossible with this particular choice.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Does "inertia" mean "sign signature of eigenvalues", basically? Thus positive definite matrices have the same inertia as $I$?

Comment: @Ian Yes.$~~~~~$